# How to make the banner image extend entire length, and logo to be centered?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am new to design and layout and I was given this wireframe:

http://problemio.com/problemionewest.pdf

and I have to make the grey border extend the entire width, and the logo to be vertically centered.

Right now I have this lol: http://www.problemio.com - the banner extends all the way across, but there is an ugly vertical line on the right side of it because of the repeat. And also, I am not sure how to make the logo image be centered. The original image is a bit large, so I need to make it some percentage of the original and align center it vertically.

Any ideas how I can do these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. set a new `height` on the `.banner`  I choose `70px`
2. give `.banner` a `background-size:100%`
3. remove `vertical-align` from `.site_title` and add `margin-top: -15px;`

**CSS**

```
.banner {
   position: relative;
   height: 70px;
   z-index: 1;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: gray;
   background-image:url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/banner_background.png');
   background-size: 100%;
}

.site_title {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -15px;
   margin-left: 20px;
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, trying it now...got the background image to look nice, but still not sure how to make the logo image resize using percentages.

Answer (score 1):

add this to *div.banner* class `background-size: 100%;`

and div.site_title `margin-top: -20px;`

oh and install firebug and do it yourself next time

Answer (score 0):

try border-right: 0;

```
.banner {
position: relative;
height: 70px;
z-index: 1;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: gray;
background-image: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/banner_background.png');
background-size: 100%;
border-right: 0;
}
```